# Executing curl from a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

How can I invoke curl command correctly from a shell script?

I have a script that actually works in one environment but doesn't on other:

I've researched a lot but still don't know what the problem is, it has to be related to fact that I'm trying to send a date time parameter that contains a space (which i have replaced by a %20). The shell runs without errors but it is not reaching the URL (I can tell that because I see no activity on the destination service)

```
dateTo=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S")
dateFrom=$(date --date='8 hour ago' +"%Y-%m-%d%%20%H:%M:%S")

/usr/bin/curl -k "https://aurl.com/JobHandlerWeb/JobSchedulerServlet?jobId=2&busSvcId=1&receivedFromDate=$dateFrom&receivedToDate=$dateTo"
```

Comment: Can you print the resulting urls on both the environments? Are they identical?

Comment: try keeping space instead of %20... it had worked for me once...

Comment: @anishsane already tried that, it didn't work at all. Then I had to add the %20 but now it is failing on other environment

Comment: Do both environments have the same version of bash?

Comment: yes, same version of bash:
echo $BASH_VERSION
4.1.2(1)-release

Comment: are the timezones different? does `date` command on both the systems at the same time give same date/time in output?

Comment: I found the issue: file format problem (created under Windows)
Thanks for your help attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue: file format problem.

I had created the file under Windows, and that was making all the difference. Even though I thought it was the same script running fine in one environment, the file format (end line characters) were different.

Corrected using Notepadd++ --> Edit --> EOL conversion

Thanks for your help attempts